# Qual formato mais apropriado para campo tipo LocalDate em JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Já vi campos de data serem retornados das seguintes formas:

```
"2012-04-23"   //Padrão ISO 8601
"23/04/2012"   //Pronto para renderização no front-end
```

Considerando o uso e flexibilidade no front-end, como realizar pesquisa em um grid  com AngularJS, fazer ordenação, etc, qual formato é mais indicado ou existe o formato certo?

Comment: Em qual linguagem está seu backend?

Comment: O backend está em Java, mas me refiro ao uso no front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acho ideal que o backend envie timestamp para o front e la você se adequa ao necessário.

**Ordenação** é melhor usar com timestamp pois é apenas um número, no `Java` será do tipo `long` ou do `wrapper` `Long`.

**Exemplo:**

```
var datasOrdenadas = datasEmTimestamp.sort(function(data1, data2) {
  return data1 > data2
});
```

Ja caso você queria **filtrar** no front-end você pode usar o poder e flexibilidade do `javascript` e seus frameworks como o `AngularJS` que você mesmo comentou, para ajustar seus objetos a suas necessidades.

**Exemplo:**

Supondo que recebeu timestamp do seu `webservice` e usando `AngularJS`.

```
var datasTratada = datasEmTimestamp.map(function(data) {
  var date = new Date(data);
  var dataTratada = {
    formatada: $filter('date')(data, 'dd/MM/YYYY - HH:mm'),
    dia: date.getDate(),
    mes: date.getMonth(),
    ano: date.getFullYear(),
    hora: date.getHours(),
    minuto: date.getMinutes()
  }
  return dataTratada;
});
```

Ai de uma lista de datas em `timestamp` você consegue uma infinidade de informações sobre as datas e pode trabalhar como quiser. No caso do `AngularJS`, de uma olhada na documentação do filtro de datas dele, é muito completo: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date.

Uma ótima biblioteca para se trabalhar com datas no javascript também é a [moment.js](https://momentjs.com).